# Swift Command Line not working while Xcode works fine - repl_swift not found

Tags: xcode, swift, command-line

I installed Xcode and when prompted to install Command Line Dev Tools on trying `swift` command on terminal, I did that too.

Now Swift runs fine in Xcode, but the command line won't work; it gives me this error message when I run it:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/repl_swift
  Reason: image not found
```

The `swiftc` command works fine.

Comment: How are you starting swift? Have you tried `xcrun swift`?

Comment: @JefferyThomas he should just be able to type `swift[return]` in Terminal to start swift. Works on my system.

Comment: `xcrun swift` gives me the same message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is a mismatch in some system libraries. You are currently using the command line tools' version of swift. As a first guess, I would try switching over to the Xcode's swift:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

then you should be able to run swift without errors.

```
xcrun swift
```

See the man page for [xcode-select](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html) for more information.

Comment: `xcrun` shouldn't be needed?

Comment: You sir are amazing, I am running Xcode Beta 6 and using `swift` simply works as well. Thank you :)

Comment: @AbhiBeckert he shouldn't be getting an error, but he is. I want to try one thing at a time. First, let's see if changing the development environment helps. After that, hopefully the command line environment will work.